# VBA Error: Ambiguous Name Detected (Excel 2010)

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA. I am sorry if my question is very easy. I have a question. When I run the following code, I get the following error message:

**Compiler Error: Ambiguous Name Detected: faren**

Can anyone please explain what part of my code is wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Dim n As Double
Private faren As Integer
Dim result As Double

Function faren(n)
faren = (9 / 5) * (n + 32)
End Function

Function c(n)
Dim c As Long
c = (5 / 9) * (n - 32)
End Function

Sub test()
result = faren(32)
MsgBox "the degree in farenheit is " & result & "Farenheit."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare faren two times. First one `Private faren As Integer` and second one `Function faren(n)`

To avoid ambiguous names you can delete `Private faren As Integer` and amend the function line like this: `Function faren(n) As Integer`

Edit: I don't know if you declare faren intentionally as `Integer` instead of `Double`, but I want you to see the following results to compare the difference:

When `Function faren(n) As Integer` is used `n = 32 --> result = 115`

When `Function faren(n) As Double` is used `n = 32 --> result = 115.2`

You might want to consider declaring `c as double` in the same way because it affects the result as well.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! :-)